Merge multiline rows in pandas dataframe based on regex pattern
I have a single column dataframe similar to this:
cat = { 'cat': ['a','b','c-','        -d','e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(cat)

>>> print(df)
          cat
0           a
1           b
2          c-
3          -d
4           e

I need to merge lines 2 and 3:
          cat
0           a
1           b
2          cd
3          e

I'm trying to use regex, since these multiline data are always of the form "-\n {8}-". However this doesn't work:
df['cat'] = df['cat'].str.replace("-\n {8}-","",flags=re.M)

I cannot use any grouping techniques, so I'm kinda stuck. Thank you for any suggestions.

are the fields to be concatenated always next to each other?

You can use a groupby approach by identifying the strings that end with - or start with  {8}-:
m1 = df['cat'].str.endswith('-')
m2 = df['cat'].str.match(' {8}-')
group = (~(m1.shift(fill_value=False) & m2)).cumsum().rename()

out = (df['cat'].groupby(group)
       .agg(lambda x: ''.join(x).replace('-        -', ''))
       .to_frame()
      )

Output:
  cat
1   a
2   b
3  cd
4   e

Intermediates:
          cat     m1     m2  group
0           a  False  False      1
1           b  False  False      2
2          c-   True  False      3
3          -d  False   True      3
4           e  False  False      4

Or without pandas, join all strings with a custom separator (e.g. \n, replace then split again):
import re

out = pd.DataFrame({'col': re.sub(r'-\n {8}-', '', '\n'.join(df['cat']))
                             .split('\n')})

Output:
  col
0   a
1   b
2  cd
3   e


The second simpler solution worked very well, thanks!

I'd do it this way:

Concatenate shifted by one/non-shifted "cat" strings
Search for your regex pattern in the newly created values
Filter/update the dataframe
Replace the multiline values with empty string

tmp = df["cat"].shift() + df["cat"]
m = tmp.str.contains(r"-\s{8,}-").eq(True)

df = df[~m.shift(-1).eq(True)]
df.update(tmp[m])

df["cat"] = df["cat"].str.replace(r"-\s{8,}-", "", regex=True)

print(df)

Prints:
  cat
0   a
1   b
3  cd
4   e


Another possible solution, which is based on the following steps:

It updates the value in the cell at row index n and column cat. This new value is calculated by adding the current value in cat to the value in the next row (n+1) of the cat column, using an empty string to fill in any missing values. The result is then cleaned by removing any occurrences of the pattern '-\n {8}-', and the value from the row index n of this cleaned series is assigned back to df.loc[n, 'cat'].

It then removes the row at index n+1 from the dataframe and resets the index to ensure it is continuous, discarding the old index.


n = 2

df.loc[n, 'cat'] = (df['cat'].add(df['cat'].shift(-1), fill_value='')
                    .str.replace(r'-\n {8}-', '', regex=True).iloc[n])
df.drop(df.index[n+1]).reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
  cat
0   a
1   b
2  cd
3   e

